# How to make a decimal to hexadecimal converter in C

Tags: c, hex, decimal

So I am an absolute beginner in C and I have to make a decimal to hexadecimal converter.

So I guess I would need to make a loop that loops until the result is 0.

But how do I make it remember all the remainders? The number is going to be input with scanf so I can't tailor the code to it.

Now I would want to do something like this

```
while(number(n)!=0)
{
    number0 / 16 = number1
    number0 % 16 = remainder0
    number1 / 16 = number2
    number1 % 16 = remainder1
    .....
    number(n-1) / 16 = 0
    number(n-1) % 16 = lastremainder
}

hex = lastremainder, ..., remainder2, remainder1, remainder0
```

But how can I make the program create variables during the loop? Do I have to use a complete different method? I took a look at other decimal to hex converters and I don't quite get how they work.

Like I said I am an absolute beginner so sorry if the question is stupid.

Thank you for the replies. So arrays are the answer to my problem? I don't fully understand them right now but thank you for the point in the right direction.

Comment: Read the decimal as a normal integer (base 10) and print it as a hexadecimal number?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think OP needs the solution without using format specifiers.

Comment: @RajuKundhe: Whyever would that be?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Completely agree... I suggested an answer using `"%x"` with `sprintf` or even just `printf`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make an array and write the remains in it:

```
int array[50];
int counter=0;

[...]

while(number!=0)
{
   [...]

   array[counter]=number%16;
   number/=16;
   ++counter;
}
```

The line `array[counter]=number%16;` means that the first element in the array will be number%16 - the second will be (number/16)%16 etc.

You need the `counter` to know how many elements there is in the array (how much remains), so that you can later write them backwards.

(Take into consideration here that you have a limit - `int array[50];` because, what happens if your number is really big and you have more than 50 remains? The solution would be to write this dynamically, but I don't think you should worry about that at this point.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't fully get this line >array[counter]=number%16;

Comment: This solution has a huge security flaw.

Comment: I was looking for a simple solution for an "absolute beginner"... :)

Comment: @Eutherpy: Using `"%x"` does seem quite a lot simpler than your solution, IMO... sorry

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: No need to apologize for something that's true. I just believe that if a task like this was given to a C beginner, it would be because it's convenient for learning some basic concepts... Once you learn from this example, of course you would use the simplest way possible. :)

Answer (score 10):

I'd simply use `sprintf`, to be honest:

```
char hex[10];
sprintf(&hex, "%x", INT_MAX);//INT_MAX macro requires limits.h, though...
printf("%s\n", hex);//prints 7fffffff
```

Job done...
In full, your code could look something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char hex[10];
    int input;
    scanf("%d", &input);
    sprintf(&hex, "%x", input);
    printf("The number %d, turned to hexadecimal is: %s\n", input, hex);
    return 0;
}
```

Or even:

```
    int input;
    scanf("%d", &input);
    printf("The number %d, turned to hexadecimal is: %x\n", input, input);
```

Comment: `sprintf(&hex,` should be `sprintf(hex,`. Also, it's better to always prefer `snprintf` over `sprintf` when you can.

Answer (score 1):

```
// decimal to hex converter
char* dec2hex(int num){
  int rem = 0,i=0;
  char hex[3];
  while(num > 0 && i >=0){
    rem = num%16;
    hex[i] = rem<10 ? (char)rem+48 : (char)rem+55;
    num/=16;
    i++;
  }
  hex[i]='\0';
  return strrev(hex);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem,.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.  In particular, are `48` and `55` supposed to be substitutes for `'0'` and `a-10`?  That's only correct in certain character codings.  And you'll need `#include <string.h>` to use `strrev()`.  What happens if `num` is negative, or greater than `0xFF`?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to be able to get size unlimited number, you need to use dynamic array.
firstly you get the input-length by loop, and then allocate array as needed.
you need to increase an index in your loop and put the current value in array[index].

Answer (score -1):

Just try this:

```
    char hex = [], finalHex = [];
while(num != 0) {
num = num/16;
rem = num%16;
switch(rem) {
case 0 : 
hex = '0';
break;
case 1 : 
hex = '1';
break;
case 2 : 
hex = '2';
break;
case 3 : 
hex = '3';
break;
case 4 : 
hex = '4';
break;
case 5 : 
hex = '5';
break;
case 6 : 
hex = '6';
break;
case 7 : 
hex = '7';
break;
case 8 : 
hex = '8';
break;
case 9 : 
hex = '9';
break;
case 10 : 
hex = 'A';
break;
case 11 : 
hex = 'B';
break;
case 12 : 
hex = 'C';
break;
case 13 : 
hex = 'D';
break;
case 14 : 
hex = 'E';
break;
case 15 : 
hex = 'F';
break;
}
strcat(hex, finalHex);
finalHex = hex;
}
 printf("%s", finalHex);
```

Comment: `string hex = ''` ? There is no `string` type in C. Also, if you use single-quoted values, these are interpreted as ints, and using strcat with those will not work...

Comment: Extremely Sorry. I wrote last c code 6 years ago. In this 6 years I only spent time on javascript. Thats why by nature I wrote string.

Comment: instead of a `switch` why not use `const char *hexMap = "0123456789ABCDEF";` and use `char hex = hexMap[someInt%16]`? just a lot shorter